# Persistent Mutate State for R dplyr (Throws error persistently until R is restarted)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm running into a super strange bug that I can't reproduce but I have console and video recording of. Basically, mutate when throwing a

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x subscript out of bounds
ℹ Input `..2` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
```

seems to have a persistent state. In the following code block, you can see that

- I load data and run a block of mutate code successfully
- I open and get a mutate error in my Shiny app and close the app
- The same original code with reloaded data now throws the same mutate error whereas it ran successfully before!
- I run an unrelated mutate that doesn't affect the original data which runs successfully
- I now reload the data a 3rd time, and the code runs successfully again now!

! I have no idea what's causing this, and obviously it's hard to reproduce. Here is some console output showing what I mean

```
# CODE RUNS SUCCESSFULLY FIRST TIME
> df_error <- read_rds('df_error.rds')
> return_data <- df_error %>%
+   dplyr::mutate(
+     new_hour = paste0(hour, ':00'),
+     across(c(contains('notional'), buy_pool, net_buy_delta, -net_notional_percent_change), scales::label_dollar()),
+     across(c(contains('percent'), contains('concentration')), scales::label_percent(accuracy=.1))
+   )

# START SHINY APP AND GET ERROR
> shiny::runApp('position_limit_engine')
Loading required package: shiny

Attaching package: ‘shiny’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:DT’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable


Attaching package: ‘plotly’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    layout

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    last_plot


Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7094
[1] 12
Warning in mean.default(hour) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
Warning in mean.default(hour) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
Warning: Error in : Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x subscript out of bounds
ℹ Input `..2` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
  135: <Anonymous>

# SAME CODE NOW ALSO THROWS ERROR
> df_error <- read_rds('df_error.rds')
> return_data <- df_error %>%
+   dplyr::mutate(
+     new_hour = paste0(hour, ':00'),
+     across(c(contains('notional'), buy_pool, net_buy_delta, -net_notional_percent_change), scales::label_dollar()),
+     across(c(contains('percent'), contains('concentration')), scales::label_percent(accuracy=.1))
+   )
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x subscript out of bounds
ℹ Input `..2` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

# RUN UNRELATED MUTATE THAT WORKS AND DOESN'T MODIFY ORIGINAL DATAFRAME
> df_error %>%
+   dplyr::mutate(
+     # hour = paste0(hour, ':00'),
+     across(c(contains('notional'), buy_pool, net_buy_delta, -net_notional_percent_change), scales::label_dollar()),
+     across(c(contains('percent'), contains('concentration')), scales::label_percent(accuracy=.1))
+   )
# A tibble: 3 x 21
  limit market period  hour num_stocks net_notional_pr… net_notional_new net_notional_de… net_notional_pe… concentration_p… concentration_n…
* <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           

    DATA

# … with 10 more variables: concentration_delta <chr>, concentration_buys_prev <chr>, concentration_buys_new <chr>,
#   concentration_buys_delta <chr>, affected_users <dbl>, affected_percentage_buyers <chr>, buy_pool <chr>, net_buy_percent_change <chr>,
#   net_buy_delta <chr>, net_buy_pool_percent_change <chr>

# CODE NOW RUNS SUCCESSFULLY AGAIN
> df_error <- read_rds('df_error.rds')
> return_data <- df_error %>%
+   dplyr::mutate(
+     new_hour = paste0(hour, ':00'),
+     across(c(contains('notional'), buy_pool, net_buy_delta, -net_notional_percent_change), scales::label_dollar()),
+     across(c(contains('percent'), contains('concentration')), scales::label_percent(accuracy=.1))
+   )
> View(return_data)
```

Anyone have any idea what could be going on? Sorry for not being able to have reproducible conditions, but I'm more looking to understand what could be causing this.

Comment: You are running this in shiny app right? Are you sure the data `df_test` is available when you are running the code?

Comment: Yes I've used browser to step into the function and check the dataframe is there. I actually saved the data from the shiny app into a .rds and loaded it in this script trying to figure out what was wrong with the dataframe, and the issue persists even just running a script outside the app.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on subset of the dataframe? Is it possible for you to share that subset?

Comment: It's hard because the behavior of the code block literally changes from successful to throwing an error, and so far I've only been able to generate the originating error by opening my shiny app.

Comment: As you can see in the edited block, I ran the code successfully, got an error in my shiny app, the code then began to throw errors, I ran an unrelated mutate that didn't affect the original data, and then the code started running successfully again.